# Make job run and do pooling every 2 mins, whether the app is closed or removed from memory

Tags: android, android-service, android-jobscheduler, android-priority-jobqueue

I am using android-priority-job-queue 'com.github.yigit:android-priority-jobqueue'. To make sure it runs every 2 minutes. Below is the code

```
public PoolingJob () {

    // This job requires network connectivity,
    // and should be persisted in case the application exits before job is completed.
    super (new Params (PRIORITY).requireNetwork ().groupBy (Const.POOLING_QUEUE_GROUP)
            .delayInMs (120000).persist ());//120 sec delay
}
```

But it get suspended whenever the app is closed or removed from memory.
How do make job run continuously and do pooling every 2 mins, when the app is closed or removed from memory. Is there anything like sticky service or [android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobService.html) ?

Building server pooling system. Require API 15 above.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) to send `Intent`s with a given interval and run the job in a `BroadcastReceiver` regardless of whether the app is running or not.

That being said, two minutes is a very short interval and you should avoid performing any task (especially network-related) that often. It will increase battery drain considerably.

Answer (score 2):

By using `AlarmManager` and `Service` you can achieve this.
Read documentation here  [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html).

Here is code block to set and remove the alarm for repeating tasks

To set The alarm

```
public void createAlarm() {
        ServerDetails serverDetails = new ServerDetails(this);
        if (serverDetails.isSettingsOK()) {
            Intent i = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
            if (PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, i,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE) == null) {
                PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0,
                        i, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
                AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
                int interval = 2 * 60 * 1000;
                alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                        System.currentTimeMillis() + interval, interval,
                        pendingIntent);
                Log.d("alarm", "alarm set successfully " + interval);
            } else {
                Log.d("alarm", "alarm already set");
            }

        }

    }
```

To Cancel the alarm

```
public void cancelAlarm() {
    Intent i = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, i,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE);
    if (pendingIntent != null) {
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
        pendingIntent.cancel();
        Log.d("alarm", "alarm cancelled");
    }
}
```

This is the service which will run in background when alarm activates.

```
public class MyService extends Service {

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {

        super.onCreate();
        Log.d("service Created", "service created");

    }


    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        super.onStart(intent, startId);
       doYourTaskHere();
    }

    private void doYourTaskHere() {

        // call here webservice or any other task here which you want to do in every two minutes

    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to 
If I were you I would look into SyncAdapters instead. You can design them to work even when you are in background and it is better architecturally than handling AlarmManagers.
Check them out here, [Sync Adapters](http://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/index.html). 
They are better for the battery performance. Allow Authentication, and add a plugin architecture to the code base.